# "gettext()" vs "gettext_lazy()" in Django

Tags: python, django, lazy-evaluation, gettext, django-i18n

I have a question about using ugettext and `gettext_lazy()` for translations.
I learned that in models I should use `gettext_lazy()`, while in views ugettext.
But are there any other places, where I should use `gettext_lazy()` too? What about form definitions?
Are there any performance diffrences between them?

**Edit:**
And one more thing. Sometimes, instead of `gettext_lazy()`, `gettext_noop()` is used. As documentation says, `gettext_noop()` strings are only marked for translation and translated at the latest possible momment before displaying them to the user, but I'm little confused here, isn't that similar to what `gettext_lazy()` do? It's still hard for me to decide, which should I use in my models and forms.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

### `gettext()` vs. `gettext_lazy()`

In definitions like forms or models you should use `gettext_lazy` because the code of this definitions is only executed once (mostly on django's startup); `gettext_lazy` translates the strings in a lazy fashion, which means, eg. every time you access the name of an attribute on a model the string will be newly translated-which totally makes sense because you might be looking at this model in different languages since django was started!

In views and similar function calls you can use `gettext` without problems, because everytime the view is called `gettext` will be newly executed, so you will always get the right translation fitting the request!

### Regarding `gettext_noop()`

As [Bryce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23448081/219519) pointed out in his answer, this function marks a string as extractable for translation but does return the untranslated string. This is useful for using the string in two places – translated and untranslated. See the following example:

```
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _, gettext_noop as _noop

def view(request):
    msg = _noop("An error has occurred")
    logging.error(msg)
    return HttpResponse(_(msg))
```

Comment: That's more understandable than the explanation at Django's documentation in my opinion. Thanks @Bernhard.

Comment: Thanks! It would also be helpful to explain when *not* to use ugettext_lazy, such as when passing it to things that expect a string like "".replace, string concatenation, and others; a lazy proxy object won't work in those cases. Otherwise this answer implies that you are safe just always using ugettext_lazy.

Comment: @mrooney those cases matter less because they will give you an error if you do them, instead of silently returning the wrong language translation. Also, you can use "".replace with ugettext_lazy, you just have to call str() on the result e.g. lazytext=ugettext_lazy('hello') and then later on use  str(lazytext).replace.

Comment: @Utku - you said it. I had absolutely no understanding after reading the docs and after reading other sources as well. This explanation is great.

Comment: what about `msg = "An error has occurred"; logging.error(msg);return HttpResponse(_(msg))? why need `_noop`?` if without `_noop`, django won't found the string need translation?

Comment: Translation works on variables. Again, here’s an identical example [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation), so why `_noop`?

Comment: But why should I _marks a string as extractable for translation_? It seems that `msg = "An error has occurred"` is functionally identical to your example…

Comment: FYI I've found that if you import one of the marking functions (e.g. `ugettext`) as `_`, and then import a second (e.g. `ugettext_noop`) using `import as` (e.g. `import ugettext_noop as _noop`), then `xgettext` won't recognize and extract the latter.  In other words, all imports other than the one you `import as _` must be imported and referenced by their full name.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: Use `**_lazy` where you might use different languages for the concerned code *even if the server is not restarted*. I've lost 2 hours because my code wasn't being translated. I had to "force" the translation by adding `str()` like `str(_("1 student failed")`

Comment: `ugettext_lazy` / `ugettext` are now deprecated. instead use `gettext_lazy` / `gettext`. The accepted answer is still valid.

Answer (score 23):

An excellent use of _noop, is when you want to log a message in English for the developers, but present the translated string to a viewer.  An example of this is at http://blog.bessas.me/posts/using-gettext-in-django/

Comment: The link is broken…

Answer (score 9):

The lazy version returns a proxy object instead of a string and in some situation it would not work as expected. For example:

```
def get(self, request, format=None):
   search_str = request.GET.get('search', '')
   data = self.search(search_str)
   lst = []
   lst.append({'name': ugettext_lazy('Client'), 'result': data})
   return HttpResponse(json.dumps(lst), content_type='application/json')
```

would fail because very last line would try serialize **lst** object into JSON and instead of a string for "client" it would have a proxy object. The proxy object is not serializeable into json.

Comment: You should use ugettext in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

[gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) can work inside functions but doesn't work outside functions.

[gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) can work inside and outside functions.

*You better use `gettext_lazy()` outside functions according to the examples of [Translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/).

### <gettext()>

This below is where `gettext()` can work:

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def hello(request):
    HttpResponse(_("Hello")) # Here
```

### <gettext_lazy()>

This below is where `gettext_lazy()` can work:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
```

```py
# "my_app1/views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

def hello(request): # Here
    HttpResponse(_("Hello"))
```

```py
# "my_app1/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

app_name = "my_app1"

urlpatterns = [
    path(_('hello'), views.hello, name="hello"),
]        # Here
```

```py
# "my_app1/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Person(models.Model):                             # Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_("name"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('person') # Here
        verbose_name_plural = _('persons') # Here
```

```py
# "my_app1/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import Person
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

admin.site.site_title = _('My site title') # Here
admin.site.site_header = _('My site header') # Here
admin.site.index_title = _('My index title') # Here

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm): # Here
    name = forms.CharField(label=_('name')) 

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    form = PersonForm
```

```py
# "my_app1/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app1'
    verbose_name = _('my app1') # Here
```