# Python, what does an underscore before parenthesis do

Tags: python, syntax

Looking through some of the Django code in authentication forms I noticed the following syntax:

```
label=_("Username")
```

Normally I would have just used a pair of quotes around the string. Can someone explain what the underscore and parenthesis around "Username" do?

Comment: Check you import statments you will find: `from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _`, your are calling `ugettext_lazy` function.  Read: [When shoud I use ugettext_lazy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160770/when-shoud-i-use-ugettext-lazy)

Comment: That's really unintuitive. A definite WFT from Python, which prides itself on avoidng these.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `_` is the name of a callable (function, [callable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111234/what-is-a-callable-in-python)). It's usually used for the `gettext` function, [for example in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation):

```
 from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
 print _("Hello!")  # Will print Hello! if the current language is English
                    # "Bonjour !" in French
                    # ¡Holà! in Spanish, etc.
```

As the doc says:

> Python’s standard library gettext module installs `_()` into the global namespace, as an alias for `gettext()`. In Django, we have chosen not to follow this practice, for a couple of reasons:
>
> [...]
>
> The underscore character (`_`) is used to represent “the previous result” in Python’s interactive shell and doctest tests. Installing a global `_()` function causes interference. Explicitly importing `gettext()` as `_()` avoids this problem.

Even if it's a convention, it **may not be the case** in your code. But be reassured, 99.9% of the time `_` is an alias for `gettext` :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice it in the imports.

Comment: What's wrong with ugettext("Hello!") ?

Comment: @ZuLu Nothing wrong, as said by the Django doc, it is a convention to use `_` as an alias so you don't have to write "gettext" every time you use a string to translate in your code. If you're using gettext only a few time in your file, you can ditch the alias and use gettext(...) directly, it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 14):

The underscore is just another Python object, but by convention the `gettext` library scans for it to find translatable text.

Usually it is bound to the `ugettext` callable:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

See [the translation chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation) of the Django documentation:

> Python’s standard library gettext module installs `_()` into the global namespace, as an alias for `gettext()`. In Django, we have chosen not to follow this practice, for a couple of reasons:
>
> - For international character set (Unicode) support, `ugettext()` is more useful than `gettext()`. Sometimes, you should be using `ugettext_lazy()` as the default translation method for a particular file. Without `_()` in the global namespace, the developer has to think about which is the most appropriate translation function.
> - The underscore character (`_`) is used to represent “the previous result” in Python’s interactive shell and doctest tests. Installing a global `_()` function causes interference. Explicitly importing `ugettext()` as `_()` avoids this problem.

Answer (score 5):

It calls the function `_` with the argument `"Username"`, just like `f("Username")` would call the function `f`. Probably `_` is a function for internationalising strings.