# String with underscore Javascript meaning

Tags: javascript, linux

I've seen in some places that strings are surrounded by _() like `_('some string')`.

For example in a desktop program with these imports:

```
const Applet = imports.ui.applet;
const St = imports.gi.St;
const Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const Keymap = Gdk.Keymap.get_default();
const Caribou = imports.gi.Caribou;
const PopupMenu = imports.ui.popupMenu;
const Lang = imports.lang;
const Gio = imports.gi.Gio;
const Main = imports.ui.main;
const MessageTray = imports.ui.messageTray;
```

What is the use of that function?

Comment: Could be the name of a callable. In python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920956/python-what-does-an-underscore-before-parenthesis-do For translation

Comment: Without knowing the sites I would guess _ is a function like
function _(text, ...) { return translate(text,...).
In order to write out some localized text

Comment: Usually this is a function defined as a translator for internationalization. It's very short because it's used a lot.

Comment: __() is for translation

Comment: That may be the meaning . Thank you.

Comment: Anyone can post a solution? I didn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer myself based on comments I got. (I already knew `_` is not anything special but a normal function name, that wasn't the question).

Based on those imports, it seems to be part of a system library. Concretely this:

```
const Lang = imports.lang;
```

It is used to translate strings into other languages automatically. For example:

```
_('Hello') //Hola
```

Answer (score 6):

It can really be anything. For instance the entire [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library is built around using `_` as a normal variable/function/class name.

`_` is not a reserved character, not any more than `i`, `a` and so on.

Practical example:

```
_('test')
//ReferenceError: _ is not defined

function _(str){
    console.log(str);
}

_('test')
//Output: test
```

More often than not, if not using underscore.js, it would be used for a function that you would use very often hence only using a single character.

Note: As stated by @Xedecimal and @AliTorabi, it is also often used to name a function defined as a translator for internationalization since once again, it is very short and used a very often.

Comment: You could note the use of it with translation and globalization :)

Comment: @AndrewL. No trouble. Otherwise edit to your liking.

Comment: Very nice answer regardless

Comment: Function declarations *hoist*, though, so the first `_('test')` in the practical example wouldn't cause errors at all.

Comment: @noppa Mmm.. sorry for not being clear I guess. But this is not one file being executed but a list of commands to run in say, a javascript console in order.

Comment: Yeah I guess that was nitpicking anyways, the meat of the answer is correct regardless of the example.

Answer (score 0):

The is NO `_` function in JavaScript, unless you implement it your self, or use an external library.

```
const _ = (str) => str.split('').join('_')
_("hello") // "h_e_l_l_o"
```