# Is there a way to override the label and help text on a FieldPanel?

Tags: wagtail

I'd like to change the help text and the label for some of the `Page` fields in the admin interface. It seems like normally the `FieldPanel` picks up the label and help text from the model field, but since I'm wanting to change these values for fields on the `Page` model (`title` and `search_description`, specifically), I can't set `verbose_name` and `help_text` on the field itself

I tried passing in the `heading` and `help_text` keyword arguments to `FieldPanel`, but I'm still seeing the default label and help text in the admin interface.

```py
class MyPage(Page):
    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('title', heading='Name', classname='full'),
        FieldPanel('search_description', heading='Description',
                   classname='full',
                   help_text='Description used in indices and search results')
    ]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a way to overwrite the default `help_text` and label (called `verbose_name`) on a per-field basis.

```
MyPage._meta.get_field("title").help_text = "Help me Obi-Wan, you're my only help_text"
MyPage._meta.get_field("title").verbose_name = "Jedi Labelling"
```

[image]

There's this method. And then there's also the MultiFieldPanel's `heading` which Dan Swain had covered nicely in his answer.

And if all that doesn't quite work, there's always the Wagtail `HelpPanel`. More on that in the docs at http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.6.1/reference/pages/panels.html#helppanel

I've also created [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Px1sRym11zg&list=PLMQHMcNi6ocsS8Bfnuy_IDgJ4bHRRrvub&index=48&t=1s) around this subject if you prefer to learn from videos.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oddly, this only seems to work for one class. e.g. if I do this for the title field's `help_text` on one class it works fine. If I then do it for the title field's `help_text` for a different page class further down the same file, then the the first class uses the help text defined for the second! Yes, I've checked I've used the correct class names.

Comment: This seems to be a known problem, and creating a custom form appears to be a better way to go. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61569075/250962

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an *easy* way to add help text directly to an individual field, but you could wrap the fields in a `MultiFieldPanel` and put a heading on it:

```
class MyPage(Page):
    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('title', heading='Name', classname='full'),
            FieldPanel('search_description', heading='Description',
                       classname='full',
                       help_text='Description used in indices and search results')
        ], heading="your help text")
    ]
```

In `wagtail.core.models.py` you will see:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class Page(AbstractPage, index.Indexed, ClusterableModel, metaclass=PageBase):
    title = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('title'),
        max_length=255,
        help_text=_("The page title as you'd like it to be seen by the public")
    )
```

Since `Page` is not an abstract class, you [can't override](http://python%20override%20field%20declaration) its fields in your own `Page`-based classes even if you try to redefine `title`.  Also, notice the import of `ugettext_lazy as _` and then the `_('title')` in the `verbose_name` declaration.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20920984/5548239) explains that this code is getting the translated version of the `title`'s `verbose_name`.

Comment: This could at least be a way to add help text to the `search_description` (which doesn't have any), but it doesn't really address the label changes. It seemed like the `heading` and `help_text` keyword args should be overriding those values in the `FieldPanel`, but maybe I've misunderstood how those are used.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, but that still doesn't really answer my question. I know you can't override the fields in the `Page` model, that's why I was asking about overriding labels and help text on the `FieldPanel`. It kinda looked like the `FieldPanel` constructor would allow you to specify those values using the `heading` and `help_text` keyword arguments, but that isn't working, so either that's not what those are for, I'm doing something wrong, or there's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion from @KalobTaulien in the Wagtail Slack that seems to do the trick:

```py
class MyPage(Page):
    pass

MyPage._meta.get_field('title').verbose_name = 'name'
MyPage._meta.get_field('search_description').help_text = 'Description used in indices and search results'
```