# I am facing an issue with language changing functionality in Django1.6

Tags: python-2.7, django-1.6, django-multilingual

I am changing the language runtime and updating it in the session variable.

I needed to call a function which will run before each method call as the language must be activated for each request. For this, I've written a middleware where in the "process_request" and the "process_response" functions, I am reading the language from session and activating it.

It is working properly in the html files (i.e. inside templates) but the text coming from the *.py files are not getting updated immediately. Not even after restarting the server or even after deleting the *.pyc files.

If I don't perform any activity in the site for 20-30 seconds then after reloading the language got updated for *.py file's text also.

Answer (score 0):

For the translation, I was using ugettext() of django.utils.translation.

By changing it from ugettext() to ugettext_lazy() worked for me.

For more information about ugettext_lazy, refer [When should I use ugettext_lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160770/when-shoud-i-use-ugettext-lazy)