# Django crispy-forms: No i18n?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

In a Django project, I translate strings using `ugettext` from the `django.utils.translation` module. As an example, I translate strings in my `models.py`.

Translation works perfectly, but not with crispy-forms. Why is that and how can I fix this?

Example `models.py`:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class CustomerUser(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        ('en', _('English')),
        ('de', _('German')),
    )

    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='en', max_length=2)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    changed_password = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In the view, I do the following:

```
from django.utils import translation

translation.activate('de')
```

but crispy forms aren't translated. The option from the `language` is still rendered as "German" instead of "Deutsch".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ugettext_lazy`.

c.f. [This great answer on "When should I use ugettext_lazy?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164683/102260)

> In definitions like forms or models you should use ugettext_lazy because the code of this definitions is only executed once (mostly on django's startup); ugettext_lazy translates the strings in a lazy fashion, which means, eg. every time you access the name of an attribute on a model the string will be newly translated-which makes totally sense because you might be looking at this model in different languages since django was started!

c.f. also The [`crispy_forms` test suite](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/blob/64606b457504a53013cb015dd4bac61b274876b9/crispy_forms/tests/test_layout.py#L18)