# What's the purpose of ugettext_noop in Django?

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation, django-i18n

As mentioned in [this section of Translation | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#marking-strings-as-no-op), the function [ugettext_noop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext_noop) is a utility function for internationalization:

> **ugettext_noop(message) [¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.ugettext_noop)**
>
> Marks strings for translation but doesn’t translate them now. This can
>   be used to store strings in global variables that should stay in the
>   base language (because they might be used externally) and will be
>   translated later.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4164683/5399734) provides an example of its usage:

```
import logging
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _, ugettext_noop as _noop

def view(request):
    msg = _noop("An error has occurred")
    logging.error(msg)
    return HttpResponse(_(msg))
```

Despite these docs, I still don't understand why should I mark a string as extractable for translation. To me it seems that `ugettext_noop` is nothing but a reminder, and even so, what's the purpose of reminding programmers that some strings (`msg` in this case) are to be translated later?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Once I have a task to make event log with storing its messages in database. It had to support i18n. So firstly I marked all event log messages with `ugettext_noop` function. In this case they were not translated before adding to database. But at the same time they were added to *.po files.

In this example `ugettext` or `ugettext_lazy` functions should be used only after extracting messages from database.

Comment: If the messages were not translated before adding to database, then why do you mark them with `ugettext_noop`? Similarly, in the example above, why not simply write `msg = "An error has occurred"`?

Comment: If I don't mark it with ugettext_noop they will not be written in *.po files. When I need to translate a message firstly I get an appropriate row from database and then do something like this:

    ugettext(event_log_row.msg)

So using `ugettext` in such a way won't add msg in *.po file.

Comment: So the reason why `msg` won't appear in a `.po` file is that it's passed to `ugettext` as a variable, rather than a string literal, so `django-admin makemessages` won't be able to detect it. Wrapping string literals with `ugettext_noop` solves this problem. Am I right?

Comment: But when you use that function, it adds the text to the `.po` file. But if you remove the text later on, the translation from the po file is removed too. This implies we have to keep "visible" the `ugettext_noop()` function in the code. If I follow your example: (1) you wrapped every string with `ugettext_noop()` so you had this in your `.po` file. (2) you moved all your strings into the database (3) when you read from the database, you call `ugettext_lazy()` to translate. This is ok, but what did you do with all the strings wrapped with `ugettext_noop()`? You couldn't remove them right?

Comment: Of course if you remove `ugettext_noop` then appropriate strings will be removed from `.po` file.